# Testing if a user-facing component of an appliance is live - check the work of my apprentice electrician friend!

Tags: safety, testing

I have a friend who is an apprentice 'sparky' as we call them here in Australia.

I asked him to test part of a heater I fixed a while back.

It no longer has a knob to turn it up and down, but instead just the bit of metal sticking out, that you can turn.

I wanted to make double-sure that bit wasn't live.

Here is what he did and I'd really appreciate your comments about whether this is the correct method or not.

---

1. Appliance plugged in and on
2. Multimeter on AC at the next highest measure over 240 volts (Australian standard voltage at power points)
3. One probe on the appliance part you want to check if live - the knob turner (doesn't matter which probe)
4. One probe into NEUTRAL hole on the (same**) power board (top RIGHT hole of the three)
5. You should get zero, not 240
   RESULT: To be precise it alternated between 000 and 001. Not sure what the sigificance of that is. Does it just do that to show that it is in fact measuring?

** This is just what he did so I would repeat it. Not sure if it would work if it was a different powerboard?

---

What does the brain trust think about this method?

Comment: Does the heater have a metallic enclosure? Does the heater have a mains plug or fixed connection? Is it earthed?

Comment: The proper way to test something like this is with a "Megger", "Hipot", or insulation tester. But for a quick safety check, this seems OK.

Comment: The test method is good enough. I think it is fine. But you might as well replace the knob on the metal shaft if  you can find one. No need to be half-assed about it. "Half-assed" is an American expression meaning "done incompletely or to a low standard of quality."

Comment: Thanks to all!
I don't know how to indicate my reply is to a specific comment, but to answer Justme:
1. The heater is metal on the outside. It's a column oil heater
2. It goes into a wall powerpoint or powerboard
3. If 'earthed' means: the power plug has the third (Australian) earth prong at the bottom, the answer is yes.

Comment: To ping a user use the `@username` syntax but remove any spaces from the username. A second test to do is to check for continuity between metal parts on the heater and the earth pin on the board. That way if the metalwork goes live a high current will flow to earth and the fuse or circuit-breaker will blow.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds fine to me - but I would also measure from the knob or other exposed metal on the appliance to the Ground/Earth pin on the power board - that should read zero as well.

It is common for a Digital Volt Meter to read +/- 1 count, so your alternating 000 and 001 is not unexpected for zero volts.